# How to take a pic without changing display in phone

Tags: android, camera

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

This is my goal. I need to pose in front of a mirror with the display facing the mirror. I need to click a pic with the same phone without changing what is displayed on the phone. Is this possible with any app yet :)

Comment: I love the idea !! +1

Comment: surfaceView of camera , we can set programmatically, but point is how to get what is there is current screen without latency ?